# How to make image list with the contents list to the right side

Tags: ionic-framework

How to make image list with the contents list to the right side.

I have tried with the thumbnail but In my project I need the image to fit half of the screen.

can someone guide how to do it.

Below is the image how I want it to be.

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ionic grid with two columns - see http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid

The first column can contain the image taking the grid cell width and height. The second column can contain the necessary content